# Passing a generic type to a method which takes a generic type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a method which takes a generic type T and passing it to a method (client.Execute) which takes a generic type

```
private T GetResult<T>(IRestRequest request)
{
    var client = new RestClient(string.Format("{0}:{1}", ApiBase, ApiPort))
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
    // omitted for brevity 
}
```

How ever the following line dosnt compile

```
var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
```

> Error 1   'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method

The Execute method is defined as follows

```
public virtual RestSharp.IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(RestSharp.IRestRequest request) where T : new()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `where T : new()` constraint in `Execute<T>()`. `GetResult<T>()` should have the same constraint.